# Abandoned theme parks in Iceland

Tags: iceland

I love hunting for abandoned places during my travels and I found one of the most exciting ruins to explore are abandoned theme parks. For example in Nara, Japan there's an incredibly well preserved abandoned theme park.

[image: Abandoned theme park in Nara, Japan]

Are there any abandoned theme parks in Iceland?

Comment: Are those you know of actually open to the public?  It seems dangerous to walk on high unmaintained constructions.

Comment: No, they are not open to the public and yes it's quite dangerous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

The most recent theme park to have to closed down in Iceland (back in 1994) was in Hveragerði but nothing remains of it today. It wasn't even much of a theme park, the rides were mostly of the mobile variety. No roller coasters or such.

There was an older one that operated in 1946 and shut down in 1965. Nothing remains of that either.

If you want to learn more you can try out the Google Translation of this article: http://www.mbl.is/greinasafn/grein/1286462/ ([translated](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=is&tl=en&u=http://www.mbl.is/greinasafn/grein/1286462/))

Comment: Seems like a good answer, but I wonder if you could provide some references?